# Bootstrap Submenu links not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, touch, submenu

I have seen this question all over the place and I have implemented multiple different solutions I have found but nothing seems to be working. I have a bootstrap collapsable menu in which contains submenus. When a submenu link is clicked, it simply closes the submenu and does not redirect to the link. I have implemented the following script which I had thought would do the trick:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
            $(this).siblings('.dropdown-backdrop').off().remove();
        }
    }, this), 0);
});
```

This script allows the submenus to dropdown on touchscreen devices, but the links aren't working. I tried removing the `e.preventDefault();` line, but that didn't seem to work either.

How can I get my submenu links to work on mobile touchscreens? They work fine on the desktop and when I hold down on the link on touchscreens I am able to open the correct link up in a new tab, but it doesn't work when you just tap it.

**EDIT:** Here is my a piece of the HTML:

```
<div class="span3">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#" tabindex='-1' class="dropdown-toggle nav-header" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class='icon-time'></i>Time Clock Management</a>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
            <li><a href="#">Labor Scheduling</a></li>
            <li><a href="/change-manager/">Change Manager</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: How about simply adding `window.location.assign(SelectYourLinkTag.href);`?

Comment: How would I select that specific link? I tried `window.location.assign($(this).attr.href);` but that tried to redirect on all the links (even the ones that are just dropdowns)

Comment: I can't tell you that if I can't see your HTML.

Comment: HTML added to question

Comment: I'll guess that Labor Scheduling is the current page and that's why it doesn't link to anywhere. Then I would use a different onclick event to direct to the appropriate link, then use `$(this)` like you tried. Something like uhm... `$('.dropdown-menu li a').click()`. If you have links that direct somewhere that are not always on that exact level of the hierarchy, hmm... Then you just might have to add a class to each menu option that states whether it's a category or a link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding the following javascript:

```
$('.dropdown-submenu ul.dropdown-menu li a').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
})
```

Comment: Working for me, thanks. However, I had to change `on('touchstart', ...)` to `click(...)`. Does it make a difference ?

Comment: Glad it worked for you as well! I'm not sure if changing `'touchstart'` to `'click'` would make much of a difference, if any.

Comment: I actualy had to change if to `click(...)` too

Comment: Just as an FYI - I *didn't* have to change `on('touchstart', ...)` to `click(...)`. And PS - thanks for the solution!